# applicationWillTerminate gets called in 4.3

Tags: iphone

I hv updated SDK and iOS to 4.3. But when i quit my app(press Home button), applicationDidEnterBackground and applicationWillTerminate methods are called.

in 4.2, this problem did not exist - only applicationDidEnterBackground was called.
What could be the possible problem? and solution, if any?

Comment: Is this really a problem? I haven't found any mention about this change in the reference, though. Suppose, it could be an enhancement to let you save application state before you get killed in background.

Comment: the problem is that my application loses the multitasking capability. It starts everytime from the beginning(applicationDidFinishLaunhing..) instead where it was left when user pressed home screen(applicationDidBecomeActive).

Comment: try using "<key>UIApplicationExitsOnSuspend</key><False/>" in the plist if you want to keep the app running in background

Comment: Already tried it. Problem exists.

Comment: In this case, check if anything is written in long before your app gets killed. If you are issuing calls to OpenGL driver or performing similar activity which is prohibited in background, you should probably disable all such activity in the applicationWillResignActive, rather than in applicationDidEnterBackground method.

Comment: Nothing is displayed in log, except my NSLog statement. I dont use OpenGL. I use MediaPlayer - iPodPlayer in app. Is this the reason for termination of app? The app doesn't terminate in simulator neither it did in 4.2.

Answer (score 0):

This is what [the documentation](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/UIApplicationDelegate_Protocol/Reference/Reference.html) says:

> For applications that support
>   background execution, this method is
>   generally not called when the user
>   quits the application because the
>   application simply moves to the
>   background in that case. However, this
>   method may be called in situations
>   where the application is running in
>   the background (not suspended) and the
>   system needs to terminate it for some
>   reason.

Nothing significant has changed in this regard between 4.2 and 4.3, so it's unclear why you're seeing a change. But whatever the cause, this is documented behaviour, therefore your app should be able to deal with it.

Comment: well, for now the problem is solved.When i commented the code in applicationDidEnterBackground, applicationWillTerminate wasn't called. Then i uncommented the commented code and ran the app again, and to my surprise, the application didn't terminate. Hope, this behavior continues.